# Cookie quickly die

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have problem with cookie at server. Cookie quickly die. At localhost  cookie good work. But the strangeness of the other. Itself cookie is present, but that code does not see it

For create cookie I used this code

```
    public void SignIn(BaseUser user, bool isRememberMe)
    {
        string data = string.Format("{0},{1}, {2}", user.Id, user.Role.RoleName, user.Role.IsSuperRole);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error", "userName");
        }

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            user.UserName,
            DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().AddDays(30),
            isRememberMe,
            data,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
            };

        if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
        {
            cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

For read and change cookie, I use this code

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        Identity id = null;

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            id = this.GetUserIdentity(authTicket);
            authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            id = new Identity();
        }

        var user = new Principal(id, id.RoleName);
        Context.User = user;
    }

    private Identity GetUserIdentity(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        string[] userDetal = ticket.UserData.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
        int id = int.Parse(userDetal[0]);
        string roleName = userDetal[1];
        bool isSuperRole;
        bool.TryParse(userDetal[2], out isSuperRole);
        string userName = ticket.Name;

        return new Identity(id, userName, true, isSuperRole, roleName);
    }
```